# How to make a custom border without breaking resize and move in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, styles, frame, wxwidgets, look-and-feel

I am writing an application in C++ using wxWidgets as the GUI library and I want to create custom windows. I want them to look like Visual Studio or 3ds Max. Is it possible to remove the border but leave resize and move functionality? I can use `wxBORDER_NONE` and catch all events to remove and resize (I hope) but in my opinion there should be easier way to customize the look of a wxFrame. Maybe something like a file which contains all needed bitmaps and settings or something like that?

Example image with these functions which I need:

[image: Example image showing custom border with blue line, custom look for exit, maximize and minimize buttons, resize and move functionality, and highlighted border]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to add an image description (for screen readers). I've also tried to make your question and title more direct, as that makes it easier for other users to quickly scan an answer questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a portable way and so wxWidgets doesn't provide any API for it. But you can do it for Windows only in the usual way, i.e. removing the normal borders (`wxBORDER_NONE` style) and handling `WM_NCHITTEST` in your overridden `MSWWindowProc()` to pretend that specific parts of your window behave as standard borders.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm trying create function in my wxApp to catch all mouse moves (no matter where cursor actually is - inside or outside my window) and nothing. I have no idea how to do this. I tried FilterEvent(wxEvent &event) but this method can catch mouse move only if cursor is inside window. Is exist any method to catch mouse move event no matter where cursor is and do this in wxApp. I want have only one "global" event handler to work with resize.

Comment: This is a completely different question which should probably be asked separately, but I can tell you that the only way to get mouse events when the mouse is not inside your window is to capture it -- which is not without its own problems and generally speaking you really shouldn't be doing this.